# Confirming an IP before starting an executable in winxp32

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

Windows question for y'all. I only have Powershell v1.0 and that's making this even more difficult, this is also my first foray into powershell. I'm a linux/OSX guy.

to make matters worse this is on a managed system, so if it didn't come with winxp base install I can't install it.

I need to do a basic while loop that pings server1, and once it has a successful ping start task.exe

All the help I can find on technet and othe MS sites and the web at large is for powershell v3 or v4.

Sorry to be a noob :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly what V1 would and wouldn't support anymore, and don't have a system I can test on but I think something like this should work:

```
do { $result = ping server1 }
until ( $result -match 'Received = [1-4]' )

& task.exe
```